# Test whether a substring is a part of a string

Tags: java

I made a program to test whether a substring is a part of another string. But it's always returning `false`.

```
public class SubString{

    public static void main(String... args){
        String findFrom = "mouse";
        String toFind = "mouse and cat";
        boolean flag = false;
        int toFindLenght = toFind.length();
        int findFromLength = findFrom.length();

        for (int x = 0; x < toFindLenght; x++) {
            char toFindIntermediate = toFind.charAt(x);

            for (int y = 0; y < findFromLength; y++) {
                char toFindFromIntermediate = findFrom.charAt(y);
                int counter = x;
                if (toFindIntermediate == toFindFromIntermediate) {
                    toFindFromIntermediate=toFind.charAt(counter);
                    counter++;

                    flag=true;
                } else {
                    flag=false;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("IS the substring a part of the string :"+flag);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not simply using `String.contains()` or `String.indexOf()`?

Comment: Ya.. i want it do it the hard way :)   I just want to know what's wrong with my logic :/

Comment: Not to pick on your name, but given the question's writing and your code formatting it was oddly fitting -.-

Comment: homework? Is so please tag it as such.

Comment: That's why I reject potential candidates who ignore the obvious `String.contains()` method. It makes peer reviewing code a pain.

Comment: how does String.indexOf() method work??

Comment: @Iam: very well. [The documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you did not break out of the loop, so even if the condition has been set to `true` in one cycle, it is reset to `false` in another cycle.

Comment: beat me :) yes like Chin said  after  'flag = true;' add 'break;'

Comment: but if I break out.. how will i test the whole sub string... won't the index be reset to 0 ? :/

Comment: What does your counter do? :)

Comment: Well it doesn't work.. it just tests for 1 word.. not the whole string :/

Answer (score 0):

I am posting here the same code with small change.

```
here what i have done is i just change the y counter of inner for loop to start from counter and added a break after flag turs true.
```

Sorry that i didn't check the negative cases. here i'm posting the editted code

```
public class SubString {
public static void main(String... args) {
    String findFrom = "mouse";
    String toFind = "mouse and cat";
    boolean flag = false;
    int toFindLenght = toFind.length();
    int findFromLength = findFrom.length();
    int counter = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < toFindLenght; x++) {
        char toFindIntermediate = toFind.charAt(x);
        for (int y = counter; y < findFromLength; y++) {
            char toFindFromIntermediate = findFrom.charAt(y);
            if(toFindIntermediate == ' '){
                break;
            }
            else if (toFindIntermediate == toFindFromIntermediate) {
                toFindFromIntermediate = toFind.charAt(counter);
                counter++;
                flag = true;
                break;
            } else if (0 != counter) {
                flag = false;
                counter = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("IS the substring a part of the string :" + flag);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using break in loops, just how I learned originally I guess, and unless there is some reason I can't have the performance loss from doing 1 extra boolean test, I avoid it. Below is your code with changes commented:

```
public class SubString {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String findFrom = "mouse";
        String toFind = "mouse and cat";
        boolean flag = false;
        int toFindLength = toFind.length();
        int findFromLength = findFrom.length(); // fixed spelling of length
        for (int x = 0; x <= toFindLength - findFromLength && !flag; x++) {
            // Changed the test in the for loop above so you won't get
            // index-out-of-bounds exceptions in the next loop.
            // char toFindIntermediate = toFind.charAt(x); // Moving this lower
            flag = true; // this lets you avoid break
            for (int y = 0, counter = x; y < findFromLength && flag; y++) {
                char toFindIntermediate = toFind.charAt(counter);
                char findFromIntermediate = findFrom.charAt(y); 
                // took "to" off above variable name for consistancy
                // int counter = x;
                if (toFindIntermediate == findFromIntermediate) {
                    // When you change the name of the variable you
                    // notice pretty quickly the assignment below is wrong.
                    // Also, you need to increment counter before you store
                    // the next char
                    // findFromIntermediate=toFind.charAt(counter);
                    // counter++;
                    // flag=true;

                    counter++;
                } else {
                    flag=false;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("IS the substring a part of the string :"+flag);
    }
}
```

And without the comments so it is a little easier to see all at once:

```
public class SubString {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String findFrom = "mouse";
        String toFind = "mouse and cat";
        boolean flag = false;
        int toFindLength = toFind.length();
        int findFromLength = findFrom.length();
        for (int x = 0; x <= toFindLength - findFromLength && !flag; x++) {
            flag = true;
            for (int y = 0, int counter = x; y < findFromLength && flag; y++) {
                char toFindIntermediate = toFind.charAt(counter);
                char findFromIntermediate = findFrom.charAt(y); 
                if (toFindIntermediate == findFromIntermediate) {
                    counter++;
                } else {
                    flag=false;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("IS the substring a part of the string :"+flag);
    }
}
```

That should do what you want while pretty much sticking to your original method.  I wouldn't show that to anyone though.  For one, your variable names are kind of backwards - normally "toFind" would be the substring you are looking for in a bigger one.  Also, you would need to clean up how you are initializing and incrementing variables in loops, just to be consistant throughout your code.  You could even switch to while loops and have it be just as clear, if not more so, or go the other direction and move everything in the inner loop into the loop declaration, and have nothing inside it.

Anyway, that should give you a working base to build from.

Comment: copying,pasting and running your code gave this-- 4 errors :(

Comment: Were they just syntax/spelling errors? I'm not on a dev machine here so no IDE to catch the simple stuff, but if it was something worse than that and the logic was bad, what was it and I will edit my answer.

Comment: Got a chance to actually test this out. The only error I had was needing to remove "int" from counter in the second for loop.  I also I put the whole thing in a loop so I could run it over and over changing the toFind and findFrom strings, and it worked like a charm.  If you are still having problems let me know.